# How do I say "to record" meaning "to audio and video record" (in contrast to "to audio record")?

Tags: ambiguity

The context here is "You should record your speech". I mean you should record both your audio (the speaking) as well as the visual (gesticulation, etc.), but the context of this sentence strongly suggests that only audio is intended. This sentence appears in sales copy and so word count is limited. "You should video record your speech" sounds clumsy. How can I phrase this smoothly and succinctly?

Comment: Ever since the advent of videotape, I'm sure plenty of harassed mums have had to [record the Queen's speech to watch it later.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22record+the+Queen's+speech+to+watch+it+later%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) In real-world contexts I think it's unlikely the mere fact of the word *speech* being there would automatically imply audio-only recording, if that wasn't what the speaker meant. Just as someone might write *"You need to say what the context is"* in a comment to a question here on ELU. No-one would interpret that as a request for an audio upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *film* your speech.  Audio recording is understood as included.

Comment: Yes. One could also use the more precise verb, *video*, though I prefer *film* myself.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Jon Hanna's comment that you could use *video* as a verb, it might be less clumsy to say

> You should *make a video* of your speech.

We used to use *videotape* as a verb, but technology has pretty much rendered that an anachronism.

While *film* still exists, it is rarely used in amateur recording. As a verb it is understandable, even if inaccurate.